# Hard disk size limit for Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 32bit

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, 32-bit, storage

How do I know how much of hard disk space system will recognize? I plan to build a file server and I am not sure whether the system is able to use 6TB hard disk drive. How can I find out limitations?

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on the file system you use. See [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) of file systems and their limitations.

Comment: I find that ext4 filesystem can support volumes with sizes up to 1 exbibyte. Does really supported volume size completely depends on filesystem? How about hardware like motherboard, BIOS etc?

Comment: I get my knowledge on this subject from [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33555/what-is-the-max-partition-supported-in-linux). Your operating system architecture, which is supported by your hardware, imposes limits on individual file size, rather than on volume size. Limits on volume size are currently largely theoretical. In the 6TB range you will have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Jos, there's nothing in that linked question that says anything like that, and it certainly isn't true.  Individual file size is only constrained by the filesystem ( FAT can only handle 4 GB ), and linux itself, which can handle 2^64 bytes.